# Alignment with two markers

Tags: horizontal-alignment, alignat

How do I get the second alignment marker at the first minus sign in the first line of the following `alignat` environment?  I would like to use it to write the second expression on two lines, aligning the plus sign preceding the sigma notation.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}


\begin{alignat*}{2}
f(x_{4}) &= (x_{4} &&- x_{1}) + (x_{4} - x_{2}) + (x_{4} - x_{3}) + \sum_{i=5}^{8} (x_{i} - x_{4}) \\
&= \bigl[(x_{4} - x_{3}) + (x_{3} - x_{1})\bigr] + \bigl[(x_{4} - x_{3}) + (x_{3} - x_{2})\bigr] + (x_{4} - x_{3}) \\
&&+ \sum_{i=5}^{8} \bigl[(x_{i} - x_{3}) - (x_{4} - x_{3})\bigr] \\
&= (x_{3} - x_{1}) + (x_{3} - x_{2}) - (x_{4} - x_{3}) + \sum_{i=5}^{8} (x_{i} - x_{3}) \\
&< (x_{3} - x_{1}) + (x_{3} - x_{2}) + \sum_{i=4}^{8} (x_{i} - x_{3}) \\
&< \sum_{i=1}^{8} \vert x_{i} - x_{3} \vert \\
&= f(x_{3}) ,
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\lvert` and `\rvert`, rather than `\vert`.

Comment: What is the advantage of using `\lvert` and `\rvert` to `\vert`?

Comment: I am replying to another comment you made to gernot.  I don't want to separate my first line into two separate lines.  The display for the first two expressions for `f(x_{4})` would not be appealing.

Comment: since you're using amsart, there's no need to add amsmath -- that's automatically loaded.

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire They are proper opening and closing symbols, whereas `\vert` is an ordinary one.

Answer (score 3):

I would align the first `-` in the second expression with the `+` in `+(x_4 - x_3)` using `aligned` inside the `align*` environment.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
f(x_{4}) &= (x_{4}-x_{1}) + (x_{4} - x_{2}) + (x_{4} - x_{3}) + \sum_{i=5}^{8} (x_{i} - x_{4}) \\
&=\begin{aligned}[t]\bigl[(x_{4} &- x_{3}) + (x_{3} - x_{1})\bigr] + \bigl[(x_{4} - x_{3}) + (x_{3} - x_{2})\bigr] \\
&+(x_{4} - x_{3})+\sum_{i=5}^{8} \bigl[(x_{i} - x_{3}) - (x_{4} - x_{3})\bigr] \end{aligned} \\
&= (x_{3} - x_{1}) + (x_{3} - x_{2}) - (x_{4} - x_{3}) + \sum_{i=5}^{8} (x_{i} - x_{3}) \\
&< (x_{3} - x_{1}) + (x_{3} - x_{2}) + \sum_{i=4}^{8} (x_{i} - x_{3}) \\
&< \sum_{i=1}^{8} \vert x_{i} - x_{3} \vert \\
&= f(x_{3}) ,
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: This does give me the proper alignment!

Answer (score 2):

An alignment like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
f(x_4) &= (x_4 - x_1) + (x_4 - x_2) + (x_4 - x_3) + \sum_{i=5}^8 (x_i - x_4) \\
&= \bigl[(x_4 - x_3) + (x_3 - x_1)\bigr] + \bigl[(x_4 - x_3) + (x_3 - x_2)\bigr] + (x_4 - x_3) \\
&\quad+ \sum_{i=5}^8 \bigl[(x_i - x_3) - (x_4 - x_3)\bigr] \\
&= (x_3 - x_1) + (x_3 - x_2) - (x_4 - x_3) + \sum_{i=5}^8 (x_i - x_3) \\
&< (x_3 - x_1) + (x_3 - x_2) + \sum_{i=4}^8 (x_i - x_3) \\
&< \sum_{i=1}^8 \vert x_i - x_3 \vert \\
&= f(x_3)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

---

Or as suggested by Thruston in the comments, with a `\qquad` instead of the `\quad`.

[image]

---

Or as suggested by Enrico, with `(x_4-x_3)` also moved to the next row.

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
f(x_4) &= (x_4 - x_1) + (x_4 - x_2) + (x_4 - x_3) + \sum_{i=5}^8 (x_i - x_4) \\
&= \bigl[(x_4 - x_3) + (x_3 - x_1)\bigr] + \bigl[(x_4 - x_3) + (x_3 - x_2)\bigr] \\
&\quad + (x_4 - x_3)+ \sum_{i=5}^8 \bigl[(x_i - x_3) - (x_4 - x_3)\bigr] \\
&= (x_3 - x_1) + (x_3 - x_2) - (x_4 - x_3) + \sum_{i=5}^8 (x_i - x_3) \\
&< (x_3 - x_1) + (x_3 - x_2) + \sum_{i=4}^8 (x_i - x_3) \\
&< \sum_{i=1}^8 \vert x_i - x_3 \vert \\
&= f(x_3) ,
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

---

Another try after clarifications in the comments:

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
f(x_4) &= (x_4 - x_1) + (x_4 - x_2) + (x_4 - x_3) + \sum_{i=5}^8 (x_i - x_4) \\
&= \bigl[(x_4 - x_3) + (x_3 - x_1)\bigr] + \bigl[(x_4 - x_3) + (x_3 - x_2)\bigr]+ (x_4 - x_3) \\
&\phantom{{}=(x_4} + \sum_{i=5}^8 \bigl[(x_i - x_3) - (x_4 - x_3)\bigr] \\
&= (x_3 - x_1) + (x_3 - x_2) - (x_4 - x_3) + \sum_{i=5}^8 (x_i - x_3) \\
&< (x_3 - x_1) + (x_3 - x_2) + \sum_{i=4}^8 (x_i - x_3) \\
&< \sum_{i=1}^8 \lvert x_i - x_3 \rvert \\
&= f(x_3)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could make that a `\qquad` to get a bit of indentation before the carried over `\sum`

Comment: @Thruston Thanks for the suggestion, I've added a note.

Comment: After seeing the result, I'd move `(x_4-x_3)` to the next line: it's left unchanged in the next step, so it belongs with the summation (and this makes the first line shorter).

Comment: @egreg I've added your version.

Comment: @gernot  I wanted the second line to be broken into two lines -
 the plus sign preceding `\sum_{i=5}^{8} \bigl[(x_{i} - x_{3}) - (x_{4} - x_{3})\bigr]` aligned with the minus sign in `(x_{4} - x_{1})` from the first line.

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire Let's see whether I've now understood what you want; see the edit of my post.

Comment: @gernot  Yes, your edited post gives me the display that I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    f(x_{4})&= (x_{4} - x_{1}) + (x_{4} - x_{2}) + (x_{4} - x_{3}) + \sum_{i=5}^{8} (x_{i} - x_{4}) \\
            &= \bigl[(x_{4} - x_{3}) + (x_{3} - x_{1})\bigr] + \bigl[(x_{4} - x_{3}) + (x_{3} - x_{2})\bigr] + (x_{4} - x_{3}) \\
            &\hphantom{{}= (x_{4}} + \mathop{\smash[b]{\sum_{i=5}^{8}}} \bigl[(x_{i} - x_{3}) - (x_{4} - x_{3})\bigr] \\
            &= (x_{3} - x_{1}) + (x_{3} - x_{2}) - (x_{4} - x_{3}) + \sum_{i=5}^{8} (x_{i} - x_{3}) \\
            &< (x_{3} - x_{1}) + (x_{3} - x_{2}) + \mathop{\smash{\sum_{i=4}^{8}}} (x_{i} - x_{3}) \\
            &< \sum_{i=1}^{8} \lvert x_{i} - x_{3} \rvert \\
            &= f(x_{3}),
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

I would not recomment that, though, as I can not see any reason on why to align to this point. But this looks like what you have tried to do above. 
I would tend to align to the first, or better second, or even better third sign from the second line. Or to use some `\quad` or alike, as recommended above, in order to stay consistent over all your formulae.

Comment: I was trying a similar code.  It is close to what I want, but you can see that the `+` preceding `\sum_{i=5}^{8} \bigl[(x_{i} - x_{3}) - (x_{4} - x_{3})\bigr]` in the second line of the code in my post is not aligned with the `-` in `(x_{4} - x_{1})` from the first line.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `multlined` from `mathtools` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
f(x_{4})
    & = (x_{4} - x_{1}) + (x_{4} - x_{2}) + (x_{4} - x_{3}) + \sum_{i=5}^{8} (x_{i} - x_{4}) \\
    & = \!\begin{multlined}[t][0.5\linewidth]
        \bigl[(x_{4} - x_{3}) + (x_{3} - x_{1})\bigr]  
        + \bigl[(x_{4} - x_{3}) + (x_{3} - x_{2})\bigr] \\
        + (x_{4} - x_{3})
        + \sum_{i=5}^{8} \bigl[(x_{i} - x_{3}) - (x_{4} - x_{3})\bigr]
        \end{multlined}   \\
    & = (x_{3} - x_{1}) + (x_{3} - x_{2}) - (x_{4} - x_{3}) + \sum_{i=5}^{8} (x_{i} - x_{3}) \\
    & < (x_{3} - x_{1}) + (x_{3} - x_{2}) + \sum_{i=4}^{8} (x_{i} - x_{3}) \\
    & < \sum_{i=1}^{8} \vert x_{i} - x_{3} \vert \\
    & = f(x_{3}) ,
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```